# Converting a Numeric column to Date column in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a column "VALUATION DATE NUM", which stores integer in '20210331' format. I have another column in the same table "VALUATION DATE" which is in date format, however is blank for now. I want to use the "VALUATION DATE NUM" column to update "VALUATION DATE" column in date format.

Using the query "UPDATE SPRD_MGMT_INP_FUND_VALUES SET "VALUATION DATE" = TO_DATE("VALUATION DATE NUM",'YYYY/MM/DD');" is giving an error "SQL compilation error: invalid type [TO_DATE(SPRD_MGMT_INP_FUND_VALUES."VALUATION DATE NUM", 'YYYY/MM/DD')] for parameter 'TO_DATE'"
Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using spaces in column names is not a good practice. Do you need something like this?

```
update yourtable SET "VALUATION DATE" = TO_DATE( "VALUATION DATE NUM"::VARCHAR,'YYYYMMDD' ) where "VALUATION DATE" is NULL;
```

Note: Because you said blank values I added the WHERE condition.

Comment: Yes i want to update the blank "VALUATION DATE" column based on "VALUATION DATE NUM" column which is in integer format '20210331'. When i run the query suggested by you i get this error "SQL compilation error: invalid type [TO_DATE(SPRD_MGMT_INP_FUND_VALUES."VALUATION DATE NUM", 'YYYYMMDD')] for parameter 'TO_DATE'"

Comment: What is the type of the column "VALUATION DATE NUM"?

Comment: "VALUATION DATE NUM"  is NUMBER(38,0) and "VALUATION DATE" is date format

Comment: Hi , you can use the TRY_TO_DATE function which will update the column with the date value if it is  a valid date and will put NULL if the data is not a valid date.